# How to block external resources in selenium web driver in Node JS?

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to block external URLs (non-domain URLs or URLs by regular expression).

I tried to use: *driver.setProxy(proxy.manual)*. However, it does not give me the flexibility to disable multiple domain names or URLs by pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with JS solutions, but you may consider using external proxies like [BrowserMob proxy](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy) it would give you opportunity to blacklist resources, in your particular case you may use standalone proxy server.